# What is the proof for the Vortex vector field equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I'm Struggling to understand why the vortex vector field is given by:

[Vortex vector field equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0qjl.png)

$\vec F(x,y) = (\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$

If anyone could explain why this is, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\vec F=-\hat x \frac {y}{x^2+y^2} +\hat y \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$, we see that

$$|\vec F|=\frac1r$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the polar coordinate for the magnitude of the position vector $\vec r=\hat r r$.

Moreover, the direction of $\vec v$ is the polar unit vector $\hat \theta$ and is perpendicular to the position vector.

Hence, $\vec F$ rotates (circulates) around the origin counterclockwise and its "strength" increases as we move closer to the origin.

A point of interest is that while $\nabla \times \vec F=0$ for all $\vec r\ne0$, the line integral of $\vec F$ is not $0$ for any (smooth) contour that encircles the origin.

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for your reply! Why is the direction of F perpendicular to the position vector r

Comment: @WillRighton: Because $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{r} = 0$, since $\vec{r} = (x , y)$ in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @willrighton Hi Will.  You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And it appears that your question was answered in another comment.